# Jquery json loop displaying only second field

Tags: jquery, json, api, loops

My current code is a loop of 2 links and I was wondering how to display only one of them at a time.
This may be a very stupid and ignorant question, so I am sorry in advance.
My code :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows? 
        client_id=40pbvj5imeg5ma36gla9p8ryfkyyyb&limit=100";
           $("#cursa").click(function() {
              $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
           $.each(result._links, function(i, field) {
        $("#curs").append('<p>' + field + '</p>');
     });
  });
});
});
```

Thank you guys !

Comment: have you considered *not* looping through all of them? considering you only want one of them...

Comment: Can you add a minimal html markup , it will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON object you are retrieving have a field named **_links**, and this one is an object with two fields on it: **self** and **next**. I have made and example, where i get both in an explicit way, hope this helps you.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows?client_id=40pbvj5imeg5ma36gla9p8ryfkyyyb&limit=100";

    $("#cursa").click(function()
    {
        $.getJSON(url, function(result)
        {
            $("#links").append("<p> SELF: " + result._links.self + "</p>");
            $("#links").append("<p> NEXT: " + result._links.next + "</p>");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cursa" type="button">Get Json</button>
<div id="links"></div>
```

I assume you only need the **next** link, so you can access it directly like the example shows.

Comment: Thanks, you`re awesome!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/sodapoppin/follows? 
    client_id=40pbvj5imeg5ma36gla9p8ryfkyyyb&limit=100";
    $("#cursa").click(function() {
        $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
            var count = 1;
            // Solution 1 Counter
            $.each(result._links, function(i, field) {
                if (count==2) {
                    $("#curs").append('<p>' + field + '</p>');
                }
                count = count+1;
            });
            // Alternative without loop for known Index
            $("#curs").append('<p>' + result._links.next + '</p>');
        });
    });
});
```